# Iterate through array backwards from index in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, arrays

I have a bit of Python code that does what I want very nicely, but trying to port that across to JavaScript is proving difficult to do cleanly.

```
jsonLine = [[0,1],[2,4],[4,8],[9,12],[11,16],[12,13]]
[firstX, firstY] = [9,12]

if [firstX, firstY] in jsonLine:
    index = jsonLine.index([firstX, firstY])

    lineArray.append(jsonLine[index:])
    lineArray.append(jsonLine[index::-1])
```

jsonLine is an array of coordinates which make up a line, and [firstX, firstY] is the starting point on a line, defined by a user. I'm creating a script that creates two lines, one in either direction from the point the user chooses, which will later be cut shorter based on distance from the user's point.

The desired output in this case will be:

```
[[[9,12],[11,16],[12,13]],[[9,12],[4,8],[2,4],[0,1]]]
```

Below is the JavaScript I have, which gets the first of the desired arrays, but using a for loop doesn't feel right, and if I use `jsonLine.reverse().slice(featureArray.length-vertex)`, it seems to duplicate the arrays pushed to lineArray. Is there a cleaner way to slice an array and reverse it?

```
for (var vertex = 0; vertex < featureArray.length; vertex++){
     if (jsonLine[vertex][0] === firstX && jsonLine[vertex][1] === firstY) {
        console.log(jsonLine.slice(vertex))
    }
```

Comment: `for (var vertex = featureArray.length - cut; vertex--; ){ ...`

Comment: You can use *slice* to create the first array, then *slice* + *reverse* to create the second, something like: `[jsonLine.slice(vertex),jsonLine.slice(vertex).reverse()]`.

Comment: @RobG unfortunately by slicing first, I just get the first of the 2 arrays I need but backwards, rather than the second one. I think `lineArray = ([[featureArray.slice(vertex)],[featureArray.reverse().slice(featureArray.length - vertex)]])` works though, thanks.

Comment: Ah, now I see what you want: `[[featureArray.slice(vertex)],[featureArray.slice(0,vertex + 1).reverse()]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a find method to find out the index of the coordinates you're interested in. After that, apply slice and reverse to get the format you're looking for:

```
var jsonLine = [
    [0, 1],
    [2, 4],
    [4, 8],
    [9, 12],
    [11, 16],
    [12, 13]
],
    el = [9, 12],
    index, res;

function findElement() {
    var i = 0;
    for (; i < jsonLine.length; i += 1) {
        if (jsonLine[i][0] === el[0] && jsonLine[i][1] === el[1]) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
index = findElement();
res = [
    [jsonLine.slice(index)],
    [jsonLine.reverse().slice(index - 1)]// -1 because you want to repeat the element.
];
console.log(res);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ph4z3vyz/1/)

Note: As **@RobG** points out in the comments of this answer, if you want to keep the array intact, substitute the second part by `jsonLine.slice(0, index + 1).reverse()`. Reverse modifies the original array and that might be undesired behaviour (though it wasn't clear in the question whether it was or not).

Comment: The second part should be `jsonLine.slice(0, index + 1).reverse()` otherwise *reverse* will modify the original array.

Comment: @RobG Thanks, it wasn't clear in the question if that was a postcondition or not. I took for granted that it wasn't. Anyway, it's a good point. I've cited you in the answer and updated it. Thank you again.